# Auto complete text view with API 21 lollipop

Tags: android

I am having problem with the auto complete text view, when I type the drop down does not show suggestion as I type in.

What I used:

1. added app compact activity
2. created another project in android studio to see what was the problem;

I used API 2.3  and when i run the application as I type the suggestion drops down

```
package com.busticketing.stallionexpress;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class AutoCompletetab_1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    //auto complete text view
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    String[] city = {"Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Lamu", "Malindi"};

    //** end of auto complete text view
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,city);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,city);
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Android);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: did you use adapter properly ?

Comment: @Altoyr check the code i added

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes correect me if im wrong :)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna alright i corrected my code..but still the dropdown doesnt show when i type...

Comment: I have copied your code and run in my device It worked successfully, Option shown. Make sure your id refer to your AutoCompleteTextView. If you are still facing the same problem then message me your java and xml class. I will return corrected code to you..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna hmm still doesnt work for me

Comment: @Salwaahmed If you are still facing the problem and want to solve then please send me your XML + Java code.. I will send you edited code. So you can copy and paste those..  
Mail me at shreekrishna@mercantile.com.np

Comment: I've sent you in your mail

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you don't have to declare adapter two times.
2. You are declaring variable named as `acTextView` and setting `adapter` to `autoCompleteTextView` which seems undefined as your codes given above.
3. Give the proper id using camel case and pascal case not like **Android** you are giving to `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Your corrected code as it is

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,city);
            AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Android);
        acTextView.setThreshold(3);
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```